# Get string between a known string and any non-alphanumeric character

Tags: c#

I have this code which allows me to get the string between "Global." and " ".

```
private string getGlobalVariableName(string text)
    {
        int pFrom = text.IndexOf("Global.") + "Global.".Length;
        int pTo = text.LastIndexOf(" ");

        string name = text.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);

        return name;
    }
```

I want to modify it so that it gets the string between "Global." and any non-alphanumeric character. How could I do this?

Example:

this is true for what I have now

getGlobalVariableName(" foo Global.bar1 foobar") == "bar1"

this is what I want to be able to do

getGlobalVariableName(" foo Global.bar1>foobar") == "bar1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex...

```
string input = "Global.bar1>foobar";
var output = Regex.Match(input, @"Global.([\w]+)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks, this does what I need.